# MFC program crashes opening files with Japanese characters in their names

Tags: windows, unicode, mfc, internationalization

I work for a software house based in the UK. We have a program that we have recently ported to 64-bit Windows. At the same time as we built a 64-bit edition we also switched from Visual Studio 2003 to 2010, continuing to use the codepage version of MFC (mfc100.dll).

Shortly after we released the program fully we received a bug report from users in Japan who use 64-bit Windows 7. If a file with Japanese characters in its name (or even with Japanese characters in the name of the folder) is opened interactively, the program fails with the message:
"Encountered an improper argument"

Trying to save a file with a new name is similar.  The Visual Studio 2003 version of the program works as expected.

The program uses the MFC class CFileDialog to prompt users and the Windows CopyFile() function to copy files to/from the user-specified location.

Are there any clues as to how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you using Unicode version?

Comment: No. It is our intention in the long term to convert it but the program dates from the time of Windows 95 and is quite large.

Comment: Andrew, did you ever get a solution for this? I am seeing the same thing on an old app I have that still uses MBCS

Answer (score 0):

If you use MBCS rather than Unicode, the Japanese paths/filenames will be handled correctly only if your system locale is set to Japanese.

If your system locale is not set to Japanese, the path/filename would be translated to your codepage and will contain garbage (frequently in form of ?????).

Set your locale to Japanese and test your program.
If it works as expected you nailed the problem.

The possible solution could then be to switch to Unicode only for CFileDialog. Call Unicode version of the underlying Win32 API rather than the CFileDialog class methods. Get all your paths/filenames as unicode (wchar_t*) and then convert them to MBCS using [WideCharToMultibyte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: The users in Japan have their system locale set to Japanese and the error messages I get trying to read and write files with Japanese names on my English-language computer are quite different.

Comment: do you get these messages  on **your** comp, when the locale set to Japanese?

Comment: The program uses the MFC OnOpenDocument() method to read files. Presumably we would need to bypass this to to get the Unicode path.

Comment: I’ve tried setting my computer to Japanese and running the debugger. When I try to open a file, CRecentFileList::Add() converts the string to UTF-16 with a call to A2W(), which calls MultiByteToWideChar() with the codepage argument set to CP_THREAD_ACP. The call to MultiByteToWideChar() interprets the filename (which was returned in the Japanese codepage) as codepage 1252 and the following call to save the filename in the registry fails with the reported exception.

Comment: What are the API you use to save it in registry?

Comment: CRecentFileList::Add() is part of MFC. It calls afxGlobalData.ShellCreateItemFromParsingName() to populate the registry.

Comment: There is a surplus call to SetThreadLocale() that was changing the thread’s codepage to English. Once it is removed files with Japanese names can be opened but only if the format language is set to Japanese as well as the system codepage.

Comment: The program calls setlocale(LC_ALL, "") at the beginning. Does that set the thread codepage to the user language?